# set border for each row, very very slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script that will make some borders like this on every line of the sheet (23 000 lines). But with my script, I can only set the borders one by one and it is very slow because it will activate the lines one by one.

Do you know how to set line borders like this, but at once? I didn't found any function that can do this to all lines at the same time.

[image: line borders]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to set the border for a complete range instead of going one row at a time?

```
    function setBorders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true,true,true,true,false,true)
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your script sets a big rectangle border but i would like to have only horizontal borders at each line.